# Confused about basic recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

```
void print(int p)
{
    if (p==0)
    {
       return;
    }

    print(p-1);
    cout<<p;
    return;
}
```

This is a basic function which counts up from whatever number you input so if you send 6 it prints 123456.

I've been staring at this for like half an hour and I can't figure out how it works. Why doesn't the recursive call `print(p-1);` just lead to the statement `if(p==0)` and return before ever even reaching `cout<<p`?

How is `cout<<p` ever accessed? I completely understand how it works when `cout<<p;` is put BEFORE the recursive call and prints like 654321 instead.

Comment: If you switch the `cout` and the `print(p-1)`, then it's the same situation as now, really. In order to get to the `return;` at the bottom, it needs to go through `print(p-1)`, or else it would never finish. It's the same thing here.

Comment: It *does* return at the if. But it does return to the next higher call of print, not to main. Then this print call continues where it waited.

Comment: You might find it helpful if you expanded `print(p-1)` into the full function  and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive calls work like a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). If we try to visualize that by expanding your calls to `print` and replacing `p` with its value, we get something like this:

```
print(4)
{
    if (4==0)
        return;
    print(3)
    {
        if (3==0)
            return;
        print(2)
        {
            if (2==0)
                return;
            print(1)
            {
                if (1==0)
                    return;
                print(0)
                {
                    if (0==0)
                        return;  // This return is called
                    print(-1)    // Line skipped
                    cout<<0;     // Line skipped
                    return;      // Line skipped
                }
                cout<<1;
                return;
            }
            cout<<2;
            return;
        }
        cout<<3;
        return;
    }
    cout<<4;
    return;
}
```

Notice that the `return` statement only leaves the current version of `print`, which is the current function on the stack. This means we end up walking all the way back up the stack that was created.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be under the impression that `return` always returns to main (or whatever the place is where you called print), and/or that a recursive call replaces itself. This is not true.

If you call `print(6)`, it starts with the `if`, of course, and then continues with `print(p-1);`. At this point, a call of `print(5)` is started, but `print(6)` from before stil exists and waits for `print(5)` to finish.

`print(5)` is doing the same, leading to a call `print(4)`, and `print(5)` waits on `print(4)`. And so on...

At some point, `print(1)` calls `print(0)`, and the `if` immediately ends the function before another `print` is called. Now, when `print(0)` ended, `print(1)` continues with its code, namely with the `cout`. After that, `print(1)` ends, leading to `print(2)` continuing its work, and so on...

Finally, when `print(5)` ends, the top-most of the nested calls (`print(6)`) continues, and after the `cout` in it, it can return to main (or from where else it was called from).

Answer (score 1):

Although there are other answers and they are all correct, I will try to explain a few more things. Using this type of recursion in C++ is only for academic purposes, but there are languages like LISP that do not have loops and rely on recursion for that.

In a recursive function, there are three key elements to take into account:

1. There must be a condition that when met ends the recursion.
2. There must be a point (maybe more than one) within the function where the function calls itself. When it does so, the invocation should be "closer" to the *end* condition. For instance, counting down, the invocation decrements the argument.
3. When the function does something along the way, that bit of work may come before or after the invocation of the recursion. Depending on how the invocation is done, we get a recursion strategy or another. You may have heard of *depth first search* or *breadth first search*.

For instance. If you do:

```
if(p<=0)
  return;

print(p-1);
cout << p;
```

You get the printing in opposite order than:

```
if(p<=0)
  return;

cout << p;
print(p-1);
```

If you first recurse and then print, you are using a *depth first* strategy. The recursion will continue until the *end* condition is met, and then the printing will be done. So the first print will be the one closer to the *end* condition; then the next; and so on. You may work out what happens in the other case.

It is also worth noting that every time you recurse, some kind of *stack* (that works in LIFO order, by the way) will have to hold the state of all previous recursions. When your problem requires a lot of recursion, you may end up using all available resources. So in languages like C++ it is always better to use a loop where only one *state* is kept.

However, recursion comes handy when you have to solve certain problems. One that comes to mind is the parsing of an expression where certain bits have different precedence than certain others. Like `1+2*3`. In this case `2*3` should be evaluated first then the result added `1+6` to yield `7`. This is called a *recursive descent parser*.

Comment: By the way, this seems like a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Think of `print(1)`: it passes the if statement, then calls `print(0)`; that returns, and the call to `print(1)` continues by calling `cout`.